# Give permission in a gmail addon

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-cloud-platform, gmail, add-on

I'm trying to put together a script for Gmail in Google Apps Scripts add-on that will reply to all email on weekends with an out of office message:

```
function autoReply() {
  var interval = 5;        //  if the script runs every 5 minutes; change otherwise
  var daysOff = [5];   // 1=Mo, 2=Tu, 3=We, 4=Th, 5=Fr, 6=Sa, 0=Su
  var date = new Date();
  var day = date.getDay();
  var label = GmailApp.getUserLabelByName("autoresponded");
  if (daysOff.indexOf(day) > -1) {
    var timeFrom = Math.floor(date.valueOf()/1000) - 60 * interval;
    var threads = GmailApp.search('is:inbox !label:autoresponded after:' + timeFrom);
    for (var i = 0; i < threads.length; i++) {
      var message = threads[i].getMessages()[0];
      if (message.getFrom().indexOf("myemail@gmail.com") < 0 && message.getFrom().indexOf("no-repl") < 0 && message.getFrom().indexOf("bounce") < 0 && message.getFrom().indexOf("spam") < 0) {
        threads[i].reply("", {
          htmlBody: "<p>Thank you for your message. We will get back to you as soon as possible. </p>"
        });
        label.addToThread(threads[i]);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I keep getting this error however:

> Exception: The script does not have permission to perform that action. Required permissions: `(https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.labels || https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.metadata || https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.readonly || https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.modify || https://mail.google.com/)`

This happened after I allowed permission in Gmail for my Gmail account. Is there something I'm missing here? Another layer that this is going through?

I tried deleting the add-on and re-allowing permissions for Gmail but no luck. The trigger for the add-on is every 5 mins just like the interval in the script.
I tried going to the links in the errors but they just came up with blank pages.

Comment: What do you mean by "deleting the add-on"? Is your script an add-on? Does it have an standard GCP?

Comment: The links in the errors are scopes.

Comment: Make sure you run the function from the editor once (to give consent) before setting up the trigger. And do this from an incognito window with no other accounts logged in.

Comment: Yes it is an add-on, for gmail. @Rubén

Comment: I tried that after deleting it and remaking it, same error @Aerials

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to set the OAuth scopes in the Google Apps Script project manifest.

---

From https://developers.google.com/workspace/add-ons/how-tos/building-gsuite-addons#verify_the_add-on_oauth_scopes

> **Verify the add-on OAuth scopes**
> Scopes define what actions the add-on is allowed to take on a user's behalf. It's a best practice for add-ons to only have scopes for actions they must have in order function and nothing more.
>
> In add-on projects, explicitly set the add-on scopes in order to ensure the add-on uses the least-permissive set of scopes possible. You define what scopes your add-on uses in the add-on manifest.
>
> See Scopes for more details.

Comment: Thank you so much. Didn't even think to look at the manifest file